# Wrapping link highlighted on return to page

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm experiencing some annoying link highlighting when returning to a page using the browser's Back button. There is an `<a>` tag that wraps an image, price, and name fields. I have set the CSS for `<a>` tags to `text-decoration: none;` and I know that this is being applied, because I can see it with Firebug. Once you click anywhere else on the page, the highlighting disappears, but it is ugly and I'd like to have it not show up in the first place. It only appears when returning from the linked page. Any ideas as to what's causing this behavior? See image below.

[image]

Comment: And how do we solve this without any code provided?

Comment: We look at the photo, then use our super-minds to decipher the CSS and HTML used...

Comment: Maybe you have a style in a:visited (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp)

Comment: I provided the code I thought relevant. I was thinking that styling the `a` selector would get all the pseudo-elements as well, but I guess that wouldn't make sense, on second thought! Thanks for the suggestion, @GeoPerez, it turned out to be an outline on the `:focus` pseudo-element, which I wasn't familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset you link style of all pseudo-classe you wanted to, like:

```
a, a:visited, a:active, a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: Eureka!  There was an `outline` being applied to the `:focus` pseudo-element!  Thanks!